# why html table td can not find images from directory?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio

My question is really boring so i am bored with it. i am C# developer. Also my CSS and html are poor. i designed a login page by using [login page](http://admin.myvirtualpaper.com/login)

why I can not see images left, right, center?

```
    <td width="198" bgcolor="" style="background-image:url(../../Styles/img/loginimages/login-left.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: bottom center"></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use relative url paths with inline style declarations. Declare the whole url or start it with just `/` to indicate it is under your domain root.

```
/mypage.png == http://mysite.com/mypage.png
```

Try

```
url(http://mysite.com/myimage.png)  //or
url(/pathtoimage/myimage.png)
```

If this were in a CSS file then you could use relative paths, but they would be in relation to the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrong path. Try to write path from root instead of relative. Something like this:

```
/Styles/img/loginimages/login-left.jpg
```

Or better put it to css file.